# How to Pass Data Back

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

This is the scene of my storyboard.

`UINavigationController` -> `UITableViewController` -> push segue -> `UIViewController`

I know how to pass the data of `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`.
 But, how can I pass the data back to the `UITableViewController`?(`UIViewController` has a navigation bar with a back button)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through the use of delegation.

When you pass data of `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`, you can set a delegate on `UIViewController`. Whenever you want to pass data back to `UITableViewController`, you can call the delegate and pass in the data

Here's a more concrete example in code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        UIViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass the UITableViewController to the UIViewController
        [vc setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Create a method on `UITableViewController` that takes data from `UIViewController` (example: `-(void)processDataFromUIViewController:(NSString *)string`)

Now when you want to pass data back to `UITableViewController`, call `[delegate sendDataFromUIViewController:@"data"]`