# XCODE 6 pass object from child to parent view controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm new with xcode ios programming i have 2 table view controllers and i want to pass object from child to parent controller. It is easy if pass from parent to child, but i can't find a simple way to pass object back from child to parent controller after a row in child view is selected.

Note: ***searchFieldController** is the parent controller

## parent header file

```
@interface ProductSearchFieldTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *selectedMake;

@end
```

## parent implement file

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *field= [self.fields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *name=[field objectForKey:@"name"];
    if([name isEqualToString: @"make"]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"valueSeque" sender:self];
    }
}
```

## Child implement file

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ProductSearchFieldTableViewController *searchFieldController = [ProductSearchFieldTableViewController alloc];
    searchFieldController.selectedMake =[[fields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"value"];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}
```

Comment: Create a property of Parent Controller in child's controller and use it by its reference.

Comment: This is a situation where one usually uses a delegate protocol.

Comment: You're creating a new instance of ProductSearchFieldTableViewController instead of accessing your parent. Besides, you shouldn't look into parentViewController as this isn't your case. You should instead implement a delegate, as suggested by @rdelmar

Comment: thank you i use delegate method :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers for this question already on StackOverflow.

Some links to answer your question:

[How to Pass Data Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550895/how-to-pass-data-back/26551211)

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)